# How to avoid "401 Unauthorized" when invoking Firebase callable HTTP Function under GCP organization?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a Firebase project under a GCP organization. I have NodeJS 10 callable functions which work fine with Firebase local emulator and in in GCP functions test page, but when attempting to call them in production using httpsCallable in a webapp, I get 401 Unauthorized - Your client does not have permission to the requested URL

There is practically nothing my test function - it just returns a hardcoded string. There is nothing in the logs after the call attempts.

The function call attempt is done after passing Firebase authentication in the webapp, and in development I see that the user is indeed passed to the context parameter.

I use Firebase Tools 8.0.2 to deploy.

In GCP console function details I see "Ingress settings - Allow all traffic", and as I wrote above, it runs successfully from the test tab there.

I tried to make the function public but I can't set permissions in the console or gcloud. When I try to run the following command with gcloud:

```
gcloud functions add-iam-policy-binding my-function-name \
 --member="allUsers" \
 --role="roles/cloudfunctions.invoker"
```

I get:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.add-iam-policy-binding) ResponseError: status=[403], code=[Forbidden], message=[Permission 'cloudfunctions.functions.setIamPolicy' denied on resource 'projects/my-project-name/locations/us-central1/functions/my-function-name' (or resource may not exist).]
```

even though my account has the following roles: Project Owner, Cloud Functions Admin, Security Admin, IAP Policy Admin, Organization Administrator

Any guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: The error message means that the credentials used by the CLI do not have permission. Double-check the account: `gcloud auth list`, your project `gcloud config list` and the roles assigned to your account `gcloud projects get-iam-policy PROJECT_ID`.

Comment: Indeed the gcloud active account was incorrect and setting it to the correct account allowed me to set IAM to make the functions public. Thanks John.

Something I don't understand is why this is needed at all if the function is invoked after passing Firebase authentication. I also tried setting allAuthenticatedUsers instead of allUsers, and still got the same error. Am I confusing two types of users?

Comment: Post an answer that shows the solution for your original question (include the steps on how you determined the solution). Then create a new question for your new question. Try not to use the comment section as a chat for additional questions.

Answer (score 3):

Per John's instructions, it turned out gcloud was set to an incorrect active account, so I set it to the correct account that had the required permissions using `gcloud config set account my-email@my-domain.com` and then I was able to make the function publicly invokable using

```
gcloud functions add-iam-policy-binding my-function-name \
 --member="allUsers" \
 --role="roles/cloudfunctions.invoker"
```