# Firebase HTTP cloud function giving 401 error when calling the function from the iOS app

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have written some cloud functions and deployed them. Initially, I was using a single function onUpdate, and it's working fine. Today I've created a simple onCall function that I'm willing to call from iOS Firebase SDK. this is the test function that I'm assuming to work but it is giving me **Unauthenticated** error in the response.

```
exports.test = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  console.log('test call info', data, context);
  return 'hello, world!';
});
```

When I check the logs on firebase, it is showing me the below logs -

[image]

Can anybody help me in resolving this issue?
Few key points -

- I've not enabled App Check.
- I'm able to access Firebase real-time DB and Firestore DB from the iOS app and from internal cloud functions (onUpdate), just facing this issue with HTTP callable functions.

Here is the iOS app code where I'm calling the cloud function -

```
   let functions = Functions.functions()
   functions.httpsCallable("test").call() { res, error in
        if let error = error {
            debugPrint(error)
        } else {
            debugPrint(res?.data)
        }
   }
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you show how you call this Cloud Function from your app?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec  I've updated my question and added the app code where I'm calling the function.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the docs about [Protocol specification for https.onCall](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference), I suggest taking a look to the paragraph [Response format: status codes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference#response_format_status_codes).

The issue seems to point to “If the auth token supplied in the request is invalid, the request is rejected with 401 Unauthorized, with an error code of UNAUTHENTICATED.”

You may find this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61159609/how-to-avoid-401-unauthorized-when-invoking-firebase-callable-http-function-un) interesting too.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer.  Been pulling my hair out for hours over this one.